# Comparison, for instance float(1.221) and c_float(1.221).value, using subtraction and epsilon or best way?

Tags: python, c

I'm working with a binary file and trying to write/read to/from this file chunks of bytes using write/readinto and using ctypes - C compatible data types (because this file using another C program too).
For instance, writing:

```
num = 1.221    
my_file_in = open('values.file', "wb")
value = c_float(num)     # writing 1.22099999... this a known problem
my_file_in.write(value)
.....
```

and reading:

```
num = 1.221
chunk = c_float()    
my_file.readinto(chunk)
```

I want to compare num and what i've read from file I khow that in chunk.value is 1.22099999... What's the best way to solve problem of comparison values of number that read and float number as `num` variable in python program? Сomparison using subtraction and epsilon or another ways?

```
math.fabs(chunk.value - num) <= epsilon
```

May be i can whatever write 1.221 in file and in future haven't problems with comparison after reading?

Answer (score 2):

The comparison using epsilon seems the best way to me.

If you think you have too large an error, you could switch from `c_float` to `c_double`, which is the C wquivalent for a Python `float`, both having 8 bytes. This is rather confusing, but it might help nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

You could use numpy.allclose:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.allclose(1.221, 1.22099999)
True
>>> np.allclose(1.221, 1.222)
False
```

Source:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html